# Sum field based on value on other field

Tags: ms-access

I have a table where I have data from sales.
The structure is

| ProductID | Items | Price | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 10 | 100 | 1 |
| a1 | 6 | 60 | 0 |
| a1 | 5 | 50 | 2 |
| a2 | 3 | 30 | 1 |
| a2 | 4 | 40 | 0 |
| a2 | 1 | 70 | 2 |

When the Action is 0 then the items not count on Sum.
When the Action is 1 then the items are count on Sum.
When the Action is 2 then the items are substruct from the Sum.

So, I want to make a Sum on Items based on Action field.

The correct result must be 5 Items on product a1 and 2 Item for the product a2.

Do you have any ideas on how can I do this?

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags and added the generic tag [[tag:sql]]. MySQL is an RDBMS and MS Access is a database application. T-SQL, on the other hand, is a dialect of SQL used by SQL Server, SyBase and other products based on  the SQL Server Data Engine (such as Azure SQL Database and Azure Edge). Please [edit] your question to tag properly.

Comment: Look at *case expressions*

Comment: @Larnu, As I see you know how to correct the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression in combination with aggregation (`group by`, `sum`):

```
select   ProductID,
         sum(case Action
                 when 2 then Items
                 when 3 then -Items
                        else 0
             end) SumItems
from     Sales
group by ProductID;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
with x (ProductID,Items,Price,Action)
as
(
  Select           'a1','10','100','1'
  union all Select 'a1','6','60','0'
  union all Select 'a1','5','50','2'
  union all Select 'a2','3','30','1'
  union all Select 'a2','4','40','0'
  union all Select 'a2','1','70','2'
)
Select 
y.ProductID,
sum(y.[Count]) as sum
from
    (
    Select 
    *,
    case when Action = 0 then 0 when Action = 1 then items when  Action = 2 then  -1*items end as Count
    from x
    ) y
GROUP by 
y.ProductID
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for other databases but this is the query for Access.

```
      select   ProductID, sum(switch (Action = 2, -Items,action=1,Items)) as 
      SumItems from Sales group by ProductID
```